# Django Templates urls not updating

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have been changing some of my views templates urls lately,
and switched from:

```
(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/view_post/$', 'view_post'),
```

to :

```
(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/post/$', 'post'),
```

in my blog application `urls.py`. And, though I did a `syncdb` and migrated
my blog application with south, the new url doesn't seem to be considered
by my sitemaps or the admin interface which redirects me on the 
old url when I'm clicking on *view this article*.

Comment: You didn't change the URL.  You just changed the view method used by the same URL.

Comment: Good point :)  I missed that.

Comment: My fault, I didn't pasted the original state as it really was... (edited to "view_post")
The old urls was really different from the current Url. 

Any ideas then? :)

Comment: Can you post your template code that calls these urls? Thanks.

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/Ksf6ZAtS
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you restarting Gunicorn? with -HUP? Sounds weird, but try killing it completely then restarting it. Also- you shouldn't need to restart Nginx, just gunicorn

```
#start command, stores pid in a file in /tmp
sudo python manage.py run_gunicorn -p /tmp/gunicorn.pid -b 127.0.0.1:8000 --daemon

#stop command
sudo kill `cat /tmp/gunicorn.pid` #note those aren't apostrophes, but the ~ key

#restart commad
sudo kill -HUP `cat /tmp/gunicorn.pid`
```

I write these as little scripts so that I can just call ./start ./stop ./restart from my main folder, makes it easier

Comment: I was actually using supervisor to manage the gunicorn. Killed every gunicorn instances on the system and tried your way, but it didn't made it. 

Does gunicorn has any kind of cache maybe?

Comment: run `ps aux | grep gunicorn` and see what come up? (I'm assuming some sort of *nix OS)

Comment: It may be safe to say that it's not the server at this point? one thing I do sometimes when I'm having problems with code updating, and I don't know how safe this is, but I'll delete the .pyc versions of files and then the .py recompile

Comment: Well I've just tried that too but it doesn't seem to make it either. I'm starting to feel desperate. I've found a little trick in order to make the old url point on the new one. But I'd like to be able to remove the legacy...

Answer (score 2):

If this is running under Apache, you would have to force-reload or restart apache for your changes to be applied.

Also, you don't have to syncdb or migrate your app when changing your urls.py map (unless you are running a custom add-on I don't know about).

Comment: I'm actually using Nginx, and already restarted it and gunicorn many times. Unfortunately no effects...

Answer (score 0):

Did you fix your urls from your [template](http://pastebin.com/Ksf6ZAtS)?  In your template, I see two instances of:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url blog.views.view_post slug=post.slug %}" />
```

The above should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url blog.views.post slug=post.slug %}" />
```

Comment: Yes, I did and it doesn't seem to change anything. Plus, my sitemap isn't updating either, so I guess the problem comes from higher then the templates... Starting to get desperate ^^

Comment: Can you post your sitemap code from your project `urls.py`?  I believe it should look something like: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#initialization.  I want to see the content of the `sitemaps` variable.