# Django not using updated urls.py - returning 404 on www.site.com/page with outdated list

Tags: django, django-views

I am very new to django and beginning to understand some of the framework however view-route binding is confusing me

There is a persistent issue that when I try to visit any url except for the homepage and `/admin` I receive a 404, including routes I have declared in my project's `urls.py` file

also i am following [this mdn tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site)

project `urls.py`

```
"""trends URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

app named 'articles' `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

app named 'articles' `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the articles index.")
```

and here is the 404 page I receive
[image: 404 page receieved upon articles/ request]

I know this is becoming very long but there is one more odd thing, when I refresh the 404 page, it will toggle between showing me the above screenshot and sometimes show me an old route which is no longer in the `urls.py` like this
[image: 404 returning outdated urls.py list]

this is on an nginx server with gunicorn, and restarting the nginx service does not solve the issue

Comment: Please check your project's `settings.py` to see if you have defined the app `articles` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. You can refer to this document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications

Comment: @Lavande I have

Comment: The configurations provided here look good to me. Maybe need to review the Django directory structure in your project. Not sure if this thread would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220959/the-current-url-app-didnt-match-any-of-these

Comment: My project and app structures are correct, according to django docs and that SO post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834109/django-templates-urls-not-updating) which lead me to the idea to restart gunicorn and that solved my problem so try running

```
sudo service gunicorn restart
```

should fix your problems

Answer (score 0):

In your projects `urls.py` you have defined

```
path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
```

So by going to `YOUR_URL/articles` will not give a valid response. Instead try going to `YOUR_URL/articles/` or change your `path` to

```
path('articles', include('articles.urls')),
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say neither of your suggestions worked for my case, the issue seems to lie elsewhere